# Javascript Touch Event at the Top of Screen for Tizen Wearable Device

Tags: javascript, tizen

I started to learn **Tizen wearable web** development just a few weeks ago. When I tried to add a "touchstart" and  a "touchend" event listener to an element at the top of screen. I found the "touchstart" event will not be triggered when I press on it. And both the two events will be triggered at the same time, which means when click activity is over, these two events will be triggered together.

This only happens to elements at the top of the screen. The tizenhwkey has been disabled, and "event.preventDefault()" is called. Both "true" and "false" have been tried as the third parameter of "addEventListener" function. Still the problem is not solved.

Has anyone ever met this problem?

Answer (score 1):

please check the following link:
https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/touch-event-top-screen-wearable-device

HTML + JS code is given there, I tested it both in emulator and device and it works.

I am using Tizen IDE
Version : 2.4.0_Rev5
Build id : 20151223-1450